# jQuery UI Accordion "navigation: true" failed on nested <ul>

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion, nested-lists

I am building an Accordion Menu using jQuery UI. But it appears to me that the `navigation: true` setter does not work for a nested `<ul>` tag.

`navigation: true` works for `Header A -> Link 1`, `Header B -> Link 2`, but not for `anything in subHeader under Header B (Link 3, Link 4)`.

May I know if I am using an incorrect structure so that the Accordion fails to function as expteced? Thank you!

Here is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        navigation: true,
        active: false,
        header: 'h3',
        collapsible: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML structure:

> #### Header A
>
> - <a href="#">Link 1</a>
>
> #### Header B
>
> - <a href="#">Link 2</a>
> - **subHeader A**
>
>   - <a href="#">Link 3</a>
>
>   **subHeader B**
>
>   - <a href="#">Link 4</a>

```
<div id="accordion">
 <h3>Header A</h3>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
 </ul>

 <h3>Header B</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li>
         <h4>subHeader A</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
         <h4>subHeader B</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>   
            </li>
       </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this problem / answer is what you are looking for :) 
[Nested accordion menu in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479270/jquery-nested-accordion-menu-problem)